# What's the meaning of $.when.apply(null, a method) in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, deferred

I'm reading the deferred object in jQuery. Could anyone please tell me what's the difference between following two invoking way?

1. `$.when.apply(null, a method).done(function(){success callback})`
2. `$.when.(a method).done(function(){success callback})`

And what kind of cases are fit for the first way above?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`$.when.apply(null, a method)` only makes sense if *a method* is actually an array or a method *call* returning an array. Then it's like a `$.when(elements, of, the, array)`. [See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) for a detailed description of the `apply` method.

`$.when.(a method)` makes no sense at all, but I guess you meant `$.when(a method)`. In this case *a method* should again be a method *call* returning a deferred object or a variable that points to a deferred object.

The syntax of `$.when()` is [`$.when(one, or, more, deferreds)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) - so if you want to pass multiple deferreds which are in an array, you need `.apply()` since you don't want to build the method call as a string and use `eval` (which is indeed **evil** in this case).

Comment: See [MDN: `fun.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) & [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter6.html#key5)

Answer (score 1):

Deferred was created to execute code after the response of some remote invocation (i.e.: ajax).

so you could have:

```
load_conf = function (user_id) {
    var def = $.Deferred()
    $("http://get_conf_data_url?user_id="+user_id).done(function (data) {
        var processed_conf = do_something_with(data);
        def.resolve(processed_conf);
    })
    return def.promise();
}
```

so you could go:

```
load_conf(1).done(function (processed_data) {
    do_something_with(processed_data);
});
```

What about to execute some code after loading exacly 3 configurations?
You could do something like:

```
$.when(load_conf(1), load_conf(2), load_conf(3)).done(function (c1, c2 ,c3) {
     console.log("configurations: ", c1, c2, c3);
})
```

But what about executing some code after loading N configurations where N is variable?
For this cases you can use the Function.prptotype.apply method.
You can pass as first argument an object that will be treated as "this" inside the function.
The second argument is the list of parameters but inside an array.

so you can go like this:

```
var defs = [];
for (var i=1; i<=N; i++) {
   defs.push(load_conf(i));
}
// here's the magic
$.when($,defs).done(function () {
   console.log("All conf loaded: ", arguments);
   // arguments contains N processed answers
});
```