# Multiple ajax jquery request issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, soap

The application has to request a web service by **$.ajax**, but the times would be multiple, and it depends on the user. Since it's dynamic, it seems that [$.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) can't work for it.

Here is the code:

```
var increase=0;
    var test_use_upload_file_name= t2_image_path+ increase;
var soap_add_new_story_image=
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
    '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ' + 
            'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" '+
            'xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'+
                '<soap:Body>'+
                    '<AddNewStoryImage xmlns="http://x.x.x.x/StoryForMac/">'+
                        '<StoryID>'+story_id+'</StoryID>'+
                        '<UserName>'+User_Name+'</UserName>'+
                        '<DragNumber>'+Drag_Number+'</DragNumber>'+
                        '<ImagePath>'+test_use_upload_file_name+'</ImagePath>'+
                    '</AddNewStoryImage>'+
                '</soap:Body>'+
            '</soap:Envelope>';   


//multiple ajax request
var start= 0;
for(;start< **USER_Decide**;start++)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: webServiceAddNewStoryImgUrl,
        contentType: "text/xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soap_add_new_story_image,     
        success: process_add_new_img_Success,
        error: process_add_new_img_Error        
    }); 
    increase++;
    test_use_upload_file_name= t2_image_path+ increase; 
}
```

Since I don't know how much pic the user will draw, I have to update the file name each time(increase++). 

Please any kind of suggestion~ Thanks!


**UPDATE**:
Sorry for my poor expression. This code WON"T WORK. My problem is similar to this [Please take a look.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368946/javascript-callback-for-multiple-ajax-calls) But the difference is that I don't know how many times I have to call the ajax request, because the user will determine it. 
Thus, I can't use the method **$.when** provided [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/). 
Is it clear?...

Comment: So what exactly is the issue?

Comment: u want a better model for this? if u have a set of html tags all having same class and storing the image paths, u can loop through those tags using a `for each` loop and get the image url from the tag currently being checked in the loop.

Comment: Please check the updated notification.

Comment: Actually, I believe (if I understand your use case correctly) that you can use `when`, using `apply`. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345124/whats-the-meaning-of-when-applynull-a-method-in-jquery).

Comment: @MasterAM             I'll try on it. Now I'm trying to solve it by recursive call: if the $.ajax call succeeded, and the method process_add_new_img_Success will fire to call the $.ajax again.
Trying...

Comment: The recursive method finally works...

Comment: @MasterAM       I will still try on it but later...

Comment: @MasterAM        Sorry, it can't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this, one one possible methods to acheive your goal http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/mNegP/

```
var object = {
    a: {
        id: 'aaa',
        text: 'bbb'
    },
    b: {
        id: 'ccc',
        text: 'cccc'
    }
};
var json = JSON.stringify(object);
console.log("JSON:", json);

//that will run callback when counter is zero
var check_success = function(num, callback) {
    console.log("one done",num,"left");
    if (num <=0) {
        callback();
    }
}

var checkloop = function() {
        var done=0;
      var num=10;// (decide by user);
//this will be called only if all requests done
var run_onlast=function() {
    console.log("last done");
    };
    //at this point we know how many ajax we would run in row
    for (var i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
        console.log("start",i);
        $.post('/echo/json/', {
        //just for sample, random delays
            json: json,delay: Math.round(Math.random()*4)
        },  "json").success(function(data) {
        //run our check function provide it with our last function and our callback
            check_success(num,run_onlast)
        }).error(function(data) {

            console.log({
                error: data.responseText
            });
        }).complete(function() {
        //always reduce, even if error
            num--;
        });
    }
        done=1;
}
    
    checkloop();
​
```

Comment: Although I can address this issue with recursive calling method(my comment above.), I  will still give it a try. If it really can work and no other better solution appears, I will choose it as the answer. Thank u.

Comment: as i understand with recursive, you will run all queries one by one,