# jQuery Promises not working for multiple jqXHR

Tags: jquery

For my jQuery Application i want to implement deferred loading.
Therefore i create an object, containing all my jqXHR promises.

when i now group all into an statement

```
var resultset = new Object();
resultset.one = $.getScript('http://......');
resultset.two = $.getScript('http://......');
```

---

```
$.when(resultset.one,resultset.two).then(
function(){ alert('success')},
function(){alert('failure')}
);
```

then it always goes to error state. I don't know why, because the js debugger tells, all request are good (status 200).

The JQ API Documentation tells that the following is going to work:

```
$.when($.ajax("/page1.php"), $.ajax("/page2.php"))
  .then(myFunc, myFailure);
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can use promises with getScript() and wait until all the scripts are loaded, something like:

```
$.when(
    $.getScript( "/mypath/myscript1.js" ),
    $.getScript( "/mypath/myscript2.js" ),
    $.getScript( "/mypath/myscript3.js" )
).done(function(){

    //place your code here, the scripts are all loaded

});
```

Comment: you're right, but then i cannot identify which of them went to error state. I thing it is useful for a meaningful error message. With the Solution i published one second before, you can watch your promises afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice explanation why:

> The syntax of `$.when()` is [`$.when(one, or, more, deferreds)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) - so if you want to pass multiple deferreds which are in an array, you need .apply() since you don't want to build the method call as a string and use `eval` (which is indeed **evil** in this case).

[What's the meaning of $.when.apply(null, a method) in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345124/whats-the-meaning-of-when-applynull-a-method-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Okay i got it working using the following workaround.
--> Maybe anyone can explain me the difference, please?

$.when.apply($, (resultset.one, resultset.two)).then(...);